# How to move on-premises database table identity column data to Azure SQL table

Tags: azure

I need to move on-premises database to Azure SQL. The structure of the database is exactly same. In my database there are tables with Indentity property on columns. I need to make Insert to these columns from my on-premises database. I need to do it through ADF copy activity on predefined schedule(say everyday). I tried various options like metioned in following links :
[Data migration to Azure with foreign key referencing an identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463080/data-migration-to-azure-with-foreign-key-referencing-an-identity-column) and [Azure Data Factory Copy Identity Column With Gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077953/azure-data-factory-copy-identity-column-with-gaps). However, I didn't get there option to copy identity column data.
Is it possible in Azure? That's my question now. And if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak with authority on the ADF copy activity, but you can write into an identity column in SQL Server/SQL Azure using the following setting:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql
This would copy the values from the SQL Server table to the SQL Azure table exactly (overriding the identity semantics)

Note that it does not make sense to allow inserts on both SQL tables while maintaining this property (assuming you are using this as a surrogate key).

If all you want to do is publish to a SQL Azure table that is "read-only" (other than for your publishing step), please note that you can also use SQL Azure as a subscriber to a transactional replication publisher attached to the on-premises SQL Server.  This may also solve your problem.

Hope that helps,
Conor Cunningham
Architect, SQL Team

Comment: Hi, yes I know by setting IDENTITY_INSERT ON we can make insert to identity columns. However, my problem was that I couldn't get an option to map identity columns from on-premises to Azure while using Copy data(PREVIEW) option of ADF.
My problem has been solved now. I have programmatically modified a pipeline to map identity columns and deployed it. Also I'm executing stored procedure on the output dataset where I'm controlling IDENTITY_INSERT.